# Create multiple handles and pass in function

Tags: matlab, handles

I am creating multiple handles for points taken from `ginput(n)` where n is no. of points to be taken. `n` is input from user.I want to create handles for all points and pass them using array to another function. SO code looks like this:

```
n=input('Enter no. of points  ');
[t]=ginput(n);
//I want to create handles for all points in t. 

function DrawBezier(//pass handles to this function )
```

I think one idea is to create an array and put handles in that. Now pass that array.

Comment: Did you try your idea? Passing the handles in an array is just about the only sensible option I think. And there's nothing wrong with it...

Answer (score 1):

`ginput` doesn't return a handle, but the cooordinates of the points clicked, so you can do something like:

```
[x,y] = ginput(n); % x and y are n x 1 arrays

function DrawBezier(x,y)
```

Comment: I will use impoint() after ginput(). impoint will create handles.

Comment: You should have said so in your original question. Once you have the coordinates `x` and `y`, you can create the handle using `h = impoint(gca,x, y)`. If you have multiple points, you can create an array of `x` and `y` coordinates, as well as an array of handles, and pass these arrays to your function as arguments.